# First experience of Foreign keys, what've I done wrong?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been hinted into giving foreign keys a go as I'm trying to get better at database programming. The problem was, if a job in the jobs table was deleted, it left orphan messages relating to it in the messages table. So foreign keys were introduced to me to be the solution.

However, I've gotten this when trying to do it, and I'm not sure what it's saying, plus, I'm not even sure which way round I should be setting the restriction, from the job to the messages, or vice versa. :(

Here's the error:

```
 #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails     (`nzua9c8_tasks`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-2929_701930'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-2929_701930_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Also, the interface for PHPMyAdmin suggested that when I delete a task, the message ID would be "restricted". I didn't have an option for delete. I want any messages with a "job_id" that matches an id in the jobs table to be deleted too.

Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `on delete cascade` to your foreign key definition (just after `on update no action` in your script).

So it would be something like:

```
 alter table messages add foreign key (id) references jobs (id) on delete cascade
```

More can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Hi, Eric. Thanks for the response, I tried something else based on your comment, now I'm getting this error, pretty similar: ALTER TABLE  `messages` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `job_id` ) REFERENCES  `nzua9c8_tasks`.`jobs` (
`id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;

Comment: I want to be able to add a job to the jobs table, then it'll be given an auto increment id, then if messages are added to the messages table, they'll also have an auto increment id, but are connected to the jobs by a job_id field. If I delete a job, I'd hope that all related messages would also be deleted. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If one job contains several messages (1:N relation) then message table should have foreign key to the jobs table.

Your error message basically says that you cant update/delete row when there is something referencing it by foreign constraint.

So if table jobs have records:

```
id name
1 job1
2 job2
```

And table of messages have records

```
id name job_id
1 mes1 1
2 mes2 2
```

Then you cant just drop record from first table. You should at first update referencing record in message table.

Also, you can change foreign key policy in such way that dependant records will be destroyed/updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys with corresponding "constraints" are for ensuring "referential integrity" and will solve the "dangling reference" problem you mentioned.

The "downside" to foreign keys is that the data must be populated into the database in the correct order:

If the rows in table "A" contain a foreign key pointer to one or more rows in table "B" then the rows in table "B" must be created before the rows in Table "A" can be created - otherwise the constraint will throw an error.